# TSQL Help with simple query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL-SERVER 2005.

I have two tables as you can see on diagram, CellularUsers and CellularPayments. I need to get  users who needs to be charged when there are few rules:

1. if last CellularPayments.paymentSum of userID was 8 then select all
   userID and userCellularNumbers where
   CellularPayments.date>getdate()
2. if last CellularPayments.paymentSum of userID was 18 then select all
   userID and userCellularNumbers where
   dateadd(dd,7,CellularPayments.date)>getdate()

[alt text http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/1946/63468037.png](http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/1946/63468037.png)

to preview diagram [click here](http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/1946/63468037.png)

**how i do it right now** but it doesn't looks right to me

```
select cu.userID,cu.userCellularNumber from CellularUsers cu
left join CellularPayments cp
on cu.userID=cp.userID
where cu.isPaymentRecurring=1
and isActivated=1
and cp.paymentID in (select max(paymentID) from CellularPayments group by userID)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm following your logic correctly, adding the following AND statement to the where clause should do it:

```
and dateadd( dd
            ,case cp.PaymentSum
               when 8 then 0
               when 18 then 7
               else [AppropriateDefaultValue]
             end
            ,CellularPayments.date) > getdate()
```

(I'd also make it an inner join.)

Comment: They can allow amazing flexiblility. (And thanks for the upvotes, they landed me on User Page #42 [Jun 17 2010]. That's got to be an SO win condition!)